MAUI .NET 8 on Android - throwing an exception
I have created a new MAUI .NET 8 project and migrated the Xamarin forms project code. When I tried to run the project with the Android device with Visual Studio Windows, which threw the exception below,
1>MSBUILD : java.exe error JAVA0000: Error in C:\Users\jeeva.nuget\packages\xamarin.androidx.collection.jvm\1.4.0.4\buildTransitive\net8.0-android34.0....\jar\androidx.collection.collection-jvm.jar:androidx/collection/ArrayMapKt.class: 1>MSBUILD : java.exe error JAVA0000: Type androidx.collection.ArrayMapKt is defined multiple times: C:\Users\jeeva.nuget\packages\xamarin.androidx.collection.jvm\1.4.0.4\buildTransitive\net8.0-android34.0....\jar\androidx.collection.collection-jvm.jar:androidx/collection/ArrayMapKt.class, C:\Users\jeeva.nuget\packages\xamarin.androidx.collection.ktx\1.2.0.9\buildTransitive\net6.0-android31.0....\jar\androidx.collection.collection-ktx.jar:androidx/collection/ArrayMapKt.class 1>MSBUILD : java.exe error JAVA0000: Compilation failed 1>MSBUILD : java.exe error JAVA0000: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to complete, origin: C:\Users\jeeva.nuget\packages\xamarin.androidx.collection.jvm\1.4.0.4\buildTransitive\net8.0-android34.0....\jar\androidx.collection.collection-jvm.jar 1>MSBUILD : java.exe error JAVA0000: androidx/collection/ArrayMapKt.class 1>MSBUILD : java.exe error JAVA0000: at com.android.tools.r8.utils.S0.a(R8_8.2.33_429c93fd24a535127db6f4e2628eb18f2f978e02f99f55740728d6b22bef16dd:135) 1>MSBUILD : java.exe error JAVA0000: at com.android.tools.r8.D8.main(R8_8.2.33_429c93fd24a535127db6f4e2628eb18f2f978e02f99f55740728d6b22bef16dd:5) 1>MSBUILD : java.exe error JAVA0000: Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to complete, origin: C:\Users\jeeva.nuget\packages\xamarin.androidx.collection.jvm\1.4.0.4\buildTransitive\net8.0-android34.0....\jar\androidx.collection.collection-jvm.jar:androidx/collection/ArrayMapKt.class 1>MSBUILD : java.exe error JAVA0000: at Version.fakeStackEntry(Version_8.2.33.java:0) 1>MSBUILD : java.exe error JAVA0000: at com.android.tools.r8.T.a(R8_8.2.33_429c93fd24a535127db6f4e2628eb18f2f978e02f99f55740728d6b22bef16dd:5) 1>MSBUILD : java.exe error JAVA0000: at com.android.tools.r8.utils.S0.a(R8_8.2.33_429c93fd24a535127db6f4e2628eb18f2f978e02f99f55740728d6b22bef16dd:82) 1>MSBUILD : java.exe error JAVA0000: at com.android.tools.r8.utils.S0.a(R8_8.2.33_429c93fd24a535127db6f4e2628eb18f2f978e02f99f55740728d6b22bef16dd:32) 1>MSBUILD : java.exe error JAVA0000: at com.android.tools.r8.utils.S0.a(R8_8.2.33_429c93fd24a535127db6f4e2628eb18f2f978e02f99f55740728d6b22bef16dd:31) 1>MSBUILD : java.exe error JAVA0000: at com.android.tools.r8.utils.S0.b(R8_8.2.33_429c93fd24a535127db6f4e2628eb18f2f978e02f99f55740728d6b22bef16dd:2) 1>MSBUILD : java.exe error JAVA0000: at com.android.tools.r8.D8.a(R8_8.2.33_429c93fd24a535127db6f4e2628eb18f2f978e02f99f55740728d6b22bef16dd:42) 1>MSBUILD : java.exe error JAVA0000: at com.android.tools.r8.D8.b(R8_8.2.33_429c93fd24a535127db6f4e2628eb18f2f978e02f99f55740728d6b22bef16dd:13) 1>MSBUILD : java.exe error JAVA0000: at com.android.tools.r8.D8.a(R8_8.2.33_429c93fd24a535127db6f4e2628eb18f2f978e02f99f55740728d6b22bef16dd:40) 1>MSBUILD : java.exe error JAVA0000: at com.android.tools.r8.utils.S0.a(R8_8.2.33_429c93fd24a535127db6f4e2628eb18f2f978e02f99f55740728d6b22bef16dd:122) 1>MSBUILD : java.exe error JAVA0000: ... 1 more
I have an in-app subscription in my project, and I used Xamarin.Android.Google.BillingClient package in migrated MAUI project.
Does this package cause this exception? is there any solution to resolve this issue?
Xamarin

Add the Xamarin.AndroidX.Fragment.Ktx package reference directly to your project. Ideally the newest available version. That will probably fix it.
https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/18665#issuecomment-1806895333
